# Which algorithms are used in autonomous robot

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am working on proposal of autonomous fire fight robots but I'm little bit confused about its sensor and algorithms. My friend suggested there are some path finding `AI` algorithms like `BFS`, `DFS`, `A*`, and `Dijkstra's Algorithm` which are used in robots, but I didn't believe it.

I want to ask: Are these algorithms used in real world robots or some other genetic algorithms? How does a robot discover path to detect, and differentiate, a human from fire?  I only want some explanation that gives knowledge.

Comment: This question is unclear. It can be improved by giving a specific problem definition that can be answered clearly and without ambiguity or opinions.

Comment: @JoshVanderHook  what you want to say does this question is broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion one possibility on how the robot could find people with fire is by using image processing. You can obtain a real time Infra red image of the outside world and then check for levels of heat measured. Using recognition alogirthms the robot could decide whether a particular figure is a human or not and if it is a human then by checking the heat generated it could decide whether the person is in danger or not. The source of heat could be the main setpoint that the robot wants to reach.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33802/discussion-on-answer-by-bhuvanesh-n-which-algorithms-are-used-in-autonomous-robo).